Publishing external POM Package to Azure Artifacts Feed Error
I have a Maven project that's using an externally provided parent POM package and I want to upload only the parent POM to Azure Artifacts.
As recommended by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines#authenticate-maven-feeds-inside-your-organization), I'm trying to achieve this by using the following command:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=biz.org.aem -DartifactId=aem-cloud-parent -Dpackaging=pom -Dfile=/path-to/artifacts/aem-cloud-parent.pom -DrepositoryId=my-azure-feed-id -Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_packaging/my-feed/maven/v1
The deploy plugin already exists in my local .m2 repository, but Maven is still trying to download it from a remote repository and failing due to a 401 Unauthorized error:
[INFO] Artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.2.0 is present in the local repository, but cached from a remote repository ID that is unavailable in current build context, verifying that is downloadable from [az-profile (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_packaging/my-feed/maven/v1, default, releases+snapshots)]
[WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml failed to transfer from https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_packaging/my-feed/maven/v1 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of az-profile has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to az-profile (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_packaging/my-feed/maven/v1): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/local/.m2/repository), az-profile (ttps://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_packaging/my-feed/maven/v1)] -> [Help 1]


How can I resolve this to successfully deploy this file to my Azure feed?

Ah, the reason for this issue has made me want to beat my head against the wall. For some reason, the -DrepositoryId parameter can't find the repository if you actually give it the ID of the Azure feed. You have to give it the name instead. I can't explain how frustrating this has been. In the Azure CLI, it accepts the feed ID too but seems Maven doesn't.

You can use the Maven task with goals: 'deploy' to publish maven packages to your feed. Please refer this document Publish Maven artifacts with Azure Pipelines for more details.
To authentication for repositories outside this organization/collection with the MavenAuthenticate@0 task, you should create a Maven service connection.

My test yaml and it works in my pipeline:
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    mavenServiceConnections: 'maven feed'

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'deploy'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: true
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false


Update
I tested the "mvn deploy:deploy-file" command in my side and it works.
My steps:

Download Apache Maven 3.9.7 here.
Extract distribution archive in any directory. Add the bin directory of the created directory apache-maven-3.9.7 to the PATH environment variable. Confirm with mvn -v in a new shell.
Create a settings.xml in the path ${user.home}/.m2 with the personal access token of your organization. It is C:\Users\myname\.m2 in my test.

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>feed name</id>
      <username>org name</username>
      <password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>


Start a new shell/command line, run the following command

mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld -Dversion=3.5 -Dpackaging=pom -Dfile=helloworld.pom -DrepositoryId=TestFeed -Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/TestFeed/maven/v1                  


Test result:




If you still meet any error, you can try to add -X in the command then it will print the detailed log for troubleshooting.

Thanks! But I didn't want to upload the artifacts through a pipeline. I wanted a way to do it manually, like with the "mvn deploy:deploy-file" command.

Hi @M.Chris, I tested the command in my side, and it works. I updated the answer with my steps. Please check if that helps. Thanks!
